# Change console colors and keep the output in C++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I need to make a CLI similar to the Window's CMD. To make the color command I'm using the functions `rlutil::setColor` and `rlutil::setBackgroundColor` in [rlutil.h](http://tapiov.net/rlutil/docs/HTML/files/docs/APIReference-txt.html). But, to change the colors in all the console I have to clear the screen (`rlutil::cls()`), or only the new outputs will appear with this changes as in the images.

Without the cls:

[image: Without the cls]

With the cls:
[image: Before the command]
[image: After the first command - colors af]

In the cmd (I used @echo off to not display the current directory):
[image: The same codes used in the cmd]

This is the function I made:

```
void colors(string value) {//I recive the user's input (like in the cmd)
    char foo[3];//I save each character in this array
    int c_text = 0, c_bg = 0;//Variables to get the numeric value of each character
    if(value.length() == 2) {//This is to only accept 2 characters as parameter for the command
        strcpy(foo, value.c_str());//Copy the values of the string in the array
        c_bg= chartoHEX(foo[0]);//Take the int value of each character 
        //(if the parameter in chartoHEX is '0', returns 0, if it's 'A', returns 10, and so on)
        c_text = chartoHEX(foo[1]);
        //If the function returns -1 means that the parameter wasn't an HEX number
        if(c_text != -1 && c_bg != -1) {
            rlutil::setColor(c_text);//Changes the text color
            rlutil::setBackgroundColor(c_bg);//Changes the background color
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the function:

```
colors("0a");
rlutil::cls();
cout << "C:\\Users\\Raven>";
```

How can I keep the output after changing the colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the low-level native Windows console functions you can change the colors without affecting the text. Get the console handle with `GetStdHandle` or `_get_osfhandle` and then call [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687407(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That didn't work but this helped me to find the solution, instead of using `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` I used `FillConsoleOutputAttribute`. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @RavenH.- How about revealing the solution here?

Comment: FillConsoleOutputAttribute fills every cell with the same color, WriteConsoleOutputAttribute specifies the colors per cell in a array. Just pick the function that best fits your needs.